# Made changes in Storyboard with wrong size class

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder, size-classes

In interface builder, I switched to the size class "Compact Regular" and started making changes. I didn't realize none of these changes would be saved to "Any Any". (Namely, I added Views, updated attributes of Views, and moved things around a little. But they're all constrained so that they should work in any size class.)

Is there a way to incorporate the changes from "Compact Regular" to "Any Any" size class?

Comment: NO! it applies only for Compact regular. it will not apply for Any Any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens pretty often. I'm sorry not.

Unluckily, there is no option to move, copy or paste constraints from a class to another.

Answer (score 3):

As at Xcode 7.2.1,

1. You can select components (views, constraints, etc) and then,
2. in Attributes selector (on the top-right panel, 4th icon from the left),
3. scroll down to bottom,
4. tick the "Installed" next to blank space that actually means "w Any h Any". There should be others in there such as "w C h R" meaning the component is only active when width is compact and height is regular.

Answer (score 1):

I've been through something like that and was able to save some work by embedding all layout elements in a view, copying, pasting it on the Any/Any class and them unembedding them again.